# how to take encrypted database backup in mysql

Tags: encryption, mysql, redhat

i am using mysql-5.5 and rhel5 and my intention is to use mysqldump to take the encrypted backup and compressed backup

as i am using mysqldump as below

```
mysqldump -u root -p db_name | gzip >file_name.sql.gz
```

it will give compressed backup but not encrypted one

Comment: explore `gpg` command.

Comment: To performed encrypted and compressed backups of your MySQL databases you can simply use MySQLBackupFTP https://mysqlbackupftp.com

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
mysqldump -u root -p db_name | gpg --encrypt -r 'user_id' | gzip >file_name.sql.gz
```

of course you need the public key of the user that you want to encrypt for.

e.g.

```
gpg --import keyfile
```

Comment: thanks for your answer,will you please explain in better way with sample key because i am not getting how to use the key

Comment: `pgp --gen-key` 

`mysqldump -u root -p db_name | gpg --encrypt -r 'UsersName users@email.com'| gzip >file_name.sql.gz `

Comment: On the key generation just follow the instructions for choosing encryption, keylength and name, email. I hope this helps :)

Comment: You shouldn't use `-p` as the password can be read out from the process list

Comment: (1) gzip is not required and waste of cpu, as gpg will compress before encrypting. (2) put the mysql password in a file dump.cnf, so it is not visible on command line, and use: mysqldump --defaults-extra-file=dump.cnf ... | gpg --encrypt -r userid  --output dump.sql.gpg

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using GPG which is frankly, kind of overkill unless you really like GPG, you can use OpenSSL which is likely built-in and has no real dependency structure for making easily portable and decryptable backups. This way you can readily decrypt the backup on just about any Linux system (and many other platforms) without any keyring, just knowing the passphrase.

Read more at [this link about how do so](http://tombuntu.com/index.php/2007/12/12/simple-file-encryption-with-openssl/).

Answer (score 1):

Also note that using `-p` via command line is really bad practise as the password can be read out via `ps aux`.

I suggest using `openssl` as `pgp` is getting to slow on big files.

The best solution I have found so far which I am regularly using at work now is [mysqldump-secure](https://github.com/cytopia/mysqldump-secure).

It offers openssl encryption and compression as well as other more features and even ships with a nagios monitoring plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Backup one database, change what is inside [..]

```
mysqldump -u root --single-transaction [DataBaseName] | gzip | openssl enc -pbkdf2 -k [MyPassword] > database.sql.zip.enc
```

Backup all databases separately:

```
date=`date "+%Y%m%d"`
for DB in $(mysql -u root -e 'show databases' -s --skip-column-names); do
        mysqldump -u root --single-transaction $DB | gzip | openssl enc -pbkdf2 -k [MyPassword] > db-$DB-$date.sql.gz.enc;
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the following Bash script that uses Dropbox to sync the backups directly to our own company server (followed by automatic backups of that data). Replace the script variables with your own. Then I just add that to my crontab to run it every 12 hours.

```
FILENAME=dbname.$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M)

SQLFILE=/root/Desktop/$FILENAME.sql
ZIPFILE=/root/Desktop/$FILENAME.zip
GPGFILE=/root/Dropbox/SQL-Backups/$FILENAME.gpg

mysqldump --user=dbuser --password=password --port=3306 --default-character-set=utf8 --single-transaction=TRUE --databases "dbname" --result-file="$SQLFILE"
zip -9 $ZIPFILE $SQLFILE
gpg --output "$GPGFILE" --encrypt --recipient "recipient@company.com" "$ZIPFILE"
unlink $ZIPFILE
unlink $SQLFILE
```

This uses GnuPG to encrypt the resulting zipped SQL dump. Remember to never import the *private* key to the web server. The web server's GPG setup only needs the public key.

You can use the [GPG software](https://gpgtools.org/) available for most platforms to create your key and publish the public key to a key server.